# c# HtmlAgilityPack class inside many classes, need to check if class exist

Tags: c#, html

I am working on this for days without a solution.

For example, I have this link: https://www.aliexpress.com/item/32682673712.html

I am trying  to check if the Buy now button disable

if I have this line inside the DOM : Buy Now

the problem is that this line inside a class that inside a class and so on...

I know there is an option to get a specific node with HtmlAgilityPack But I didn't succeed

```
var nodes = doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//div[(@class='next-btn next-large next-btn-primary buynow disable')]/p");
```

but I don't get anything

I tried to get the entire dom and then search with inside but didn't succeed

```
var getHtmlWeb = new HtmlWeb();
var document = getHtmlWeb.Load(url);
```

I just got the html and not the DOM

another thing I tried to do is:

```
    var Driver = new FirefoxDriver();
    Driver.Navigate().GoToUrl(url);
    string pagesource = Driver.PageSource;
```

and it did works! but this solution open the browser and I don't want that (I am running over many links)

Please help a frustrated guy :)

thanks.

Comment: Did you try document2,document3, and document5.  It been a while since I had similar issues.  You can cast the different documents and then get more elements and properties.  I do not remember what is valid and what isn't.  The DOM is in the 2,3,and 5 documents.

Comment: https://html-agility-pack.net/knowledge-base/tag/javascript may be worth a read.

Answer (score 0):

This is happening because the buynow button is being loaded via JavaScript.

If you open network tab in chrome dev tools, you will notice that the page is making a call to some api to load the product information.

The url with json data for the product looks like this:
`https://www.aliexpress.com/aeglodetailweb/api/store/header?itemId=32682673712&categoryId=100007324&sellerAdminSeq=202460364&storeNum=720855&minPrice=4.99&maxPrice=4.99&priceCurrency=USD`

You will most probably have to send same headers as chrome is sending for the request in order to load the api endpoint in your app.